# Is there a way I could sync my Facbook galleries with my Android Gallery?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sync, facebook, gallery

Is there a way that allows me to sync my Facebook galleries to my Android phone if possible? I use HaxSync but that only seems to handle the calendar and the contacts, and the Facebook app doesn't have any such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Photosync is set as "ON" by default IMO. Anyways read [this](http://wccftech.com/sync-android-photos-facebook-guide/)

Comment: Please don't post link only answers.